# Need help containerizing app that works in Google App Engine, Flex Environment

Tags: python, docker, build, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to containerize an app that I have working with App Engine, Flex environment. I'm able to use Cloud Build to create the Docker image, store in Cloud Registry, and spin up GKE pods. However, after deploying and exposing, I get the following error:

```
severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 19, in <module>
    app = worldgiftart.create_app(config)
  File "/app/worldgiftart/_init_.py", line 40, in create_app
    from .crud import crud
  File "/app/worldgiftart/crud.py", line 15, in <module>
    from worldgiftart import get_model, storage
  File "/app/worldgiftart/storage.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.cloud import storage
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_init_.py", line 38, in <module>
    from google.cloud.storage.blob import Blob
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 54, in <module>
    from google.cloud.iam import Policy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.cloud.iam'
```

Here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Open port 80 for serving the webpage
EXPOSE 80

# Run main.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

And here's `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.1.2
google-cloud-datastore==1.12.0
google-cloud-storage==1.28.1
gunicorn==20.0.4
oauth2client==4.1.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
PyMySQL==0.9.3
Flask-PyMongo==2.3.0
PyMongo==3.10.1
six==1.14.0
```

Any suggestions what to check or change?

Thanks - Joe

Comment: Did you tried to run locally in docker? Seems python is not locating your module, try to check the python path, running the container locally could help in debug process.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give that a shot. I think the issue is probably that I'll need to set up some authentication for Cloud Datastore - something that when deploying to App Engine is handled automatically but not with a local docker.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue is the difference between App Engine and GKE. Deploying to App Engine automatically handles assigning the service account with the proper permissions; not so with GKE. One has to establish the service account and bind the proper permissions. Thanks to all who took a look. Hope this helps someone in the future.